# Git: Getting a Branch Name from a PR

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I went ahead and followed [this guide](https://davidwalsh.name/pull-down-pr) to allow me to checkout branches by their PR number rather than the branch name.

However, I am wondering if the reverse is possible, allowing me to get the branch name given a PR number from the command line. Is it doable?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no: there's no mapping (offered by GitHub by a standard Git-oriented interface, at least) showing the target branch of a pull request.  However, all hope is not lost!  The [GitHub Pull Request API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/) can give you the *status* of an existing pull request: `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number` returns a rather large JSON blob that has the required information.

Note that parsing this JSON blob requires additional tools.

Comment: `jq` should handle the json parsing very easily

Answer (score 1):

Turns out not through github directly, but can be done through the very powerful `hub` CLI tool created by Github themselves.

https://github.com/github/hub

With a combination of hub and parsing tools, you can checkout PR number 6350 like this:

```sh
git checkout $(hub pr list -f "%I|%H|%n" | grep "6350.*" | cut -d "|" -f2)
```