# GIT how to get branch name from a PR created from a fork

Tags: git, fork, branch, pull-request

I'm trying to get the branch name from a Pull-Request created from a fork using git command line.
I have looked around but the only thing i found was how to checkout the pr locally by giving a custom name.

How can I retrieve the original branch name?

Comment: PR means Pull Request?

Comment: yes sorry I will edit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: Getting a Branch Name from a PR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623918/git-getting-a-branch-name-from-a-pr)

Comment: Yep, calling the API works for me. I can get hold of the ref name. Perfect. Thank you

Comment: New `gh` CLI tool also seems to have that check out functionality: https://cli.github.com/manual/examples#checking-out